# Problems Viewing Voyager Tables after integrating Iseed from Github using Laravel 7

Tags: laravel, voyager

[image]

I am making a multi seller ecommerce website using Laravel 7. After integrating an Iseeder package from Github overriding my current Voyager seeders, I seem to have issues in my Voyager admin panel. I'm not sure if this is the real issue here but I can't view tables in Roles, Users and other pages. BREAD functions are still working properly. Also, when I try to edit Users i'm getting the error "ErrorException
Trying to get property 'details' of non-object (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\itprojETONA\vendor\tcg\voyager\resources\views\users\edit-add.blade.php)"

I have no idea what seems to be the problem as I'm just starting to learn Laravel. I hope someone here can help me. Thanks a lot!

PHP 7.3.22
Laravel 7x
Composer version 1.10.13
Voyager 1.4x

Comment: lets say you have an object named obj and it had property details, you access that property using `$obj->details` , so if you are passing non-object i.e null in place of $obj it will throw the error `ErrorException Trying to get property 'details' of non-object` , so you need to debug that line for some value if you are passing null or no value then it will throw this error, Hope that helps :)

Comment: for more help show your code then only we can debug